# GCP : Finding list of users present in AD group

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, active-directory

I have created one Active Directory group 'AAA-xxxxx@xyz.com'. Now I want to fetch all the members of this group so that I can create Bigquery dataset for each of the member. So whenever new user is added to this AD group , his personal bigquery dataset will be created.

I tried cloud identity but it didn`t worked out :-

`gcloud identity groups memberships list --group-email='AAA-xxxxx@xyz.com'`

**ERROR: (gcloud.identity.groups.memberships.list) Invalid value for [--group-email]: There is no such a group associated with the specified argument:AAA-xxxxx@xyz.com**

Comment: I am struggling with this exact issue ! @user2401323 any luck finding a solution ?